# Expo Linking + React Navigation not opening path

Tags: expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

The issue is that when i open my app through the browser with exp://.../--/user then the app doesnt redirect me to the specified Userscreen.

```
... other imports ...
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');

export default function Route() {

  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
      screens: {
        HomeScreen:'home',
        userPosts: "post",
        profileOther: "user",
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 400 }}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='userPosts' component={SingleVideo} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='profileOther' component={ProfileScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='savePost' component={SavePostScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        ... other screens ...
      </Stack.Navigator>
      <Modal />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: no used expo-linking at the end